# Does python's WSGI specification have anything to say about websockets?

Tags: python, websocket, wsgi, flask-socketio

I know that there are options out there for WSGI servers that can handle websockets. Ex: [this](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deployment.html) allows running flask + websockets in gunicorn, which is a WSGI server. But I thought the WSGI spec was only concerned with HTTP? Does the spec mention websockets and if not, how is something like `flask-socketio` possible?

Comment: no, it does not. But look for "python ASGI" instead.

Comment: I am aware of ASGI, I just don't know how people are able to take WSGI servers and make them work with websockets.

Comment: the verb fot writting code like that is "to hack". so, there are hacks working around the WSGI spec - most likely creating a view that never returns, or otherwise going through layers and accessing network resources one normally would not do with a well behaved WSGI app.

Comment: Besides getting the data and  essentially "kidnapping" the HTTP request that initiates a websocket, there will be a hack needed in the running software as well, as WSGI code is intended to be composed of synchronous functions that will do their job and keep no state about each request. Something will have to run _in parallel_ to the WSGI server loop which just call the HTTP views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WSGI specification does not define how to work with WebSocket. That did not stop some web servers from adding custom extensions to WSGI to implement this. Gunicorn, uWSGI, Werkzeug, gevent, eventlet and Meinheld all have their own way to support WebSocket in their WSGI implementations. Sadly none of them are compatible with each other.

In case you are curious, the main issue with adding WebSocket support is that WSGI does not pass the actual network socket to the application, because it assumes it will not need it. Obviously this is required for WebSocket because the route needs to be able to freely read and write data. Many of the extensions I referenced above add a custom element to the `environ` dictionary with this socket.